# Having difficulties getting navigation to work in Django

Tags: python, django

I am trying to get my navigation to work in Django

This is what my about.html looks like

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
<li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'courses' %}">Courses</a></li>
```

urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from catalog import views
from django.urls import path,include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('', views.about, name='about'),
    path('', views.courses, name='courses')
]
```

and views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
#home page view
def index(request):
    return render(request, "index.html")
#about page
def about(request):
    return render(request,"about-us.html")
#courses page
def courses(request):
    return render(courses, "courses.html")
```

As suggested by one of the answers, I made these changes to my urls.py file

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('about/', views.about, name='about'),
    path('courses/', views.courses, name='courses')
]
```

I am now getting this error message

```
AttributeError at /courses/
'function' object has no attribute 'META'
Request Method:
GET
Request URL:
http://127.0.0.1:8000/courses/
Django Version:
2.2.7
Exception Type:
AttributeError
Exception Value:
'function' object has no attribute 'META'
Exception Location:
C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\template\context_processors.py in debug, line 40
Python Executable:
C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\python.exe
Python Version:
3.7.4
```

Comment: You can't have three views with the same URL. Use different paths for each one.

Comment: You don't have paths for your pages. Try putting # or index/ etc.

Comment: @furkanayd # is not a path, it cannot be used in URLs.

Comment: @Daniel Roseman Isn't # sign not a unicode char? I assume that it can be used for describing a path, as any unicode character.

Comment: That's not relevant. The issue is that a browser would never send # as part of a URL, as it is the fragment identifier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just update your urls.py to the following:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from catalog import views
from django.urls import path,include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('about/', views.about, name='about'),
    path('courses/', views.courses, name='courses')
]
```

Comment: I seem to be getting the error message 'function' object has no attribute 'META'
 with this

Comment: Oh wait, I see it, you're missing your request in the view. Should be: 

def courses(request):
    return render(request, "courses.html")